# Reset Safari SSL Exceptions on iOS 11

Tags: security, mobile-safari, certificate, ssl

On iOS if you visit a website with an invalid SSL certificate, you are presented with this prompt (ok, it’s in italian but you get the picture):

[image]

Tapping “show details” allows the user to proceed to the website, assuming he understands the security implications.

In my case I had to accept a self signed certificate to a local web server but it’s not required anymore.

The problem is that I didn’t find any way to remove this exception to make safari show the warning again (restoring settings doesn’t seem to work).

Do I really have to perform a full restore?